# Why are uploaded images stored at Imgur and not Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, images, imgur

If I (or you) upload an image on Stack Exchange, it goes to Imgur. Why has it been developed this way, and not to be stored on Stack Exchange's servers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Outsourcing something like image hosting makes sense. It means that you don't have to do it - it requires *a lot* of disk space and bandwidth to serve the images. When you're starting a new website that's likely to need to serve images it's one cost you can fix.

It's also one less thing that you don't have to maintain and update.